# call spring method on jqgrid button click

Tags: jquery, spring, jqgrid

I need to Call the spring controller method in the onclick of the button in footer? Can anyone tell how to do this?

```
.navGrid("#pagingDiv",{search:false, edit:false,add:false,del:false}).navButtonAdd('#pagingDiv',{
               caption:"Export Devices", 
               buttonicon:"ui-icon-add", 
               onClickButton: function(){ 
                 alert("Export Devices");

                         // Call spring controller method
               }, 
               position:"last"
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by javascript/ajax by calling this method inside of your onclick event. Here i showed way to get this done by jquery ajax method.

```
function submitData() {
$.ajax({
    //Use the URL how you are send your request from jsp page to spring controller.
    url : "URL",
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {
        //Anything you need to get it back.
    }
});}
```

Let me know if this helps..